# Why is a zero matrix a reduced row echelon from?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why is a zero matrix a reduced row echelon from?

Doesn't a matrix need to have a leading $1$ in order to be a reduced row echelon?

Answer (score 1):

No. The definition of row-echelon form says that all *non-zero* rows must start with a one. Otherwise it would be impossible to reduce a matrix like:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$